# Is there any difference between mobileEmulation and setting the user agent in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, chrome-web-driver

I want to simulate mobile devices for testing and automation purposes. Using the Chromedriver and Selenium I have found 2 ways to do this. I can either set the user agent (example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940477/selenium-2-setting-user-agent-for-ie-and-chrome)):

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Or I can enable mobile emulation (example from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation)):

```
from selenium import webdriver

mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "Google Nexus 5" }
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)

driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities())
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score -3):

User agent string: you are essentially lying to the web server about your browser.

Emulation mode: you are essentially lying to yourself about your browser.